# Change IP address of Sony camera remote API endpoint URL

Tags: ip-address, sony, sony-camera-api

I would like to change the IP address of the camera (FRD-X 3000) of the end point URL described in the Device description searched by SSDP.

Comment: stackoverflow is issue solving site.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you actually will not be able to change the camera's ip address. You will only be able to query the camera to have it give you it's endPoint ip address.